# InstallShield run a ".exe"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exe, installshield, installshield-2010

Is it possible [I'm pretty sure it is] for InstallShield to run a ".exe" to install prerequisite components

I'm new to the software and have never used it before so I'm not sure if there is a term for what I want to achieve

I have been given the install [.ism?] project which is for the most part already configured but currently it checks for these components [DsoFileSetup_KB224351_x86.exe and owc10.exe] and alerts the user that they need to be installed before progressing directing them to a site where the file can be downloaded and installed separately, I have been tasked with incorporating these into the installer I'm using InstallShield 2010 to build it

Is someone able to point me to where I need to look for having an unattended .exe to run?

Many thanks

Comment: Last time I used InstallShield this was called a "Custom Action."  You should be able to find that in the manual.  See also http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q102426

Comment: Custom actions aren't appropriate for installing prerequisites.

Comment: What version of InstallShield?  What project type are you using?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherPainter I'm using InstallShield 2010, the project type is and Excel project with ~70 components [addins]

Comment: Project types are InstallScript, Basic MSI, InstallScript MSI... not the type of application you are deploying.

Comment: I'm creating a Setup.exe

Comment: All three of those project types can create a setup.exe.  Open the project up in InstallShield and read what it says in the title bar.